# LXD Error Cannot Start Container

Tags: ubuntu, lxd

I was creating an Ubuntu container using LXD :

```
lxd launch ubuntu first
```

When I received this error :

```
error : Error calling 'lxd forkstart /var/lib/lxd/containers /var/log/lxd/ubuntu/lxc.conf' : err='exit status 1'
```

I looked at the log and recieved this message at the ending :

```
 lxc 1443307966.953 WARN lxc_cgmanager - cgmanager.c:cgm_get:993 - do_cgm_get exited with error
```

Comment: You might wish to take a look at [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/946). It seems to be a bug in recent kernels, which manifests if `nfs-server` and/or `nfs-common` are also installed (at least, that's also been my experience). There's a workaround there which involves binding `/proc` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc/proc` manually before starting a container, if that's something you'd want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error isn't fatal so it's likely something else that you're running into.

If using a PPA, I'd strongly recommend that you run:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The reason for this being that LXC version 1.1.2 which shipped in some Ubuntu releases had a small ABI breakage that'd lead to containers failing to start when not upgraded to version 1.1.3 first.

If that doesn't help, then make sure lxd is running the latest upstream version (0.22 at the moment) and if that still doesn't fix it, I'd recommend you file an upstream bug report at https://github.com/lxc/lxd so we can look into it.